# Convert Linux datetime to Windows local datetime format

Tags: c#, linux, windows, datetime, ssh

I have a function that ssh Linux machine and run date command on it, and return Linux machine date in string format. When I try to convert that string into datetime format it gives an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Following is my code:

```
DateTime appservertime = Convert.ToDateTime(GetLinuxServerTime(kvp.Value));

public string GetLinuxServerTime(string ip)
{
    using (var client = new SshClient(ip.Trim(), UserName, Password))
    {
         string a = "";
         client.Connect();
         SshCommand x = client.RunCommand("date");
         a = x.Result.ToString();
         //a.value= Tue Jun 19 11:54:34 EDT 2018

         client.Disconnect();
         return a;
    }
}
```

I need to convert the Linux datetime into the local machine datetime format (not hardcoded format).

Comment: You can use [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Actually, I am working on windows service which will be deployed on production servers, and different servers might have different time formats. so, can't specify the format in DateTime.ParseExact. @itsme86

Comment: What is the return value of `GetLinuxServerTime(kvp.Value)` method exactly? You should debug your code and tell us.

Comment: Why not keep it simple and set up ntpd on the linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a format for the `date` command:

```
date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

and use the C# equivalent of that format to parse the string back to a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime appservertime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    GetLinuxServerTime(kvp.Value), "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

So like this:

```
DateTime appservertime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    GetLinuxServerTime(kvp.Value), "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

public string GetLinuxServerTime(string ip)
{
    using (var client = new SshClient(ip.Trim(), UserName, Password))
    {
         client.Connect();
         SshCommand x = client.RunCommand("date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
         string a = x.Result.ToString();

         client.Disconnect();
         return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its still giving the invalid datetime error. Following is my code: 

DateTime appservertime = DateTime.ParseExact(GetLinuxServerTime(kvp.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

SshCommand x = client.RunCommand("date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"");

Comment: What is the string value returned by `GetLinuxServerTime()`? Does that value contain any whitespace or newlines?

Comment: Yeah. There were whitespace. Working fine now. Thanks Peter.